# Why does NSNotificationCenter fail in simulator but works on real devices?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am using NSNotificationCenter to pass messages from async web service calls back to a main menu UIViewController, this works 100% of the time on real devices, but fails in the Xcode simulator, should this not work in the simulator?

Code below is in viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(tillIsReadyToUse:)
                                                 name:@"tillConfigObjectDownloaded" object:nil];
```

And in the web service call I am sending this from the completion block

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                                              postNotificationName:@"tillConfigObjectDownloaded" object:nil];
```

Why does this work every time on real devices and fail in the simulator?

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug! Find out what the problem is in the simulator. Is the web service call being called? Is the notification being posted? Does the observer exist at that time? And so on. — Also, you might have a threading problem; make no assumptions about what thread the notification will be posted on! If it comes in on a background thread, Weird Things can happen.

Comment: thanks for the answer, let me clarify, the debugger shows that the web service is called correctly, the notification seems not to be posted as the receiver don't receive it, is there a way to debug the actual posting? is there a way to force the listener and the sender to the same thread?

Comment: Debugging notifications is extremely difficult because you cannot introspect the notification center and find out whether your observer has been unregistered — I once spent days before I discovered that my own code was unregistering me prematurely (I figured it out using symbolic breakpoints). And of course if the observer goes out of existence the posting will fail silently (again, some clever debugging can show you if that's what's happening). If `tillIsReadyToUse` is called but on a background thread, you might need to step out to the main thread before proceeding.

Comment: Alternatively, don't use notifications! The fact that you are using them at all is a possible "Bad Smell". Use delegation, or provide a closure that the web service delegate can call back into.

Comment: Tillisreadytouse is not called in the simulator but 100% of time on real devices, I will look into the threading concerns thanks

Comment: If it is not called _at all_, that's not a threading issue per se. You would do better to focus on the lifetime / deregistration of the observer. One more thing: if you must use notifications, use a block-based notification, not a selector-based notification. This makes the observer a different object from `self` and its lifetime and unregistration can be easier to control (though you can also get a memory leak on `self` if you're not careful).